# R - Exclude numbers from series

Tags: r

Ok so I have a series of numbers. I am looking to exclude values less than -0.10. However, if a number over -0.10 appears after the first -0.10 it is to be ignored.

I am so far trying to use `dplyr` for the task grouping by `rleid`, and then trying to come up with a way to use `row_number()` so in my first series of numbers, I can mark the position of the `first` value below -0.10. Once I know the row_number, any other values `after` the first instance can be ignored and exluded from the output.

I am using this dummy data:

```
x <- c(0,0,-0.07347,-0.08351,-0.09091,-0.10624,-0.08087,-0.10677,-0.14588,-0.13901,-0.13689,0,0,0,-0.09091,0.10624,0.08087,0.10677,0,0)
y <- c(0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0)        
df <- data.frame (x,y)

# Remove leading 1 on x column
df$z <- ifelse(df$x <0 | df$x >0, 1,0)

# Exclude values (all less than -0.1)
df$output <- ifelse(df$z  == 1 & df$x > -0.1 ,1,0)
```

the desired output is when `df$z == 1` and on the first instance of `<-0.10`... `print 0` until the end of the series (regardless of the value of the following numbers)

this image shows this and correct output is in green.

[image]

***EDIT**

**Solution:** 
Handling of multiple runs over -0.010

```
df %>%
  group_by(rleid=rleid(z)) %>%
  mutate(outcome=as.numeric(!row_number() > row_number(z==1 & x < -0.1))) %>%
  mutate(outcome=replace(outcome,z == 1 & x < -0.1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(outcome=replace(outcome,z == 0, 0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% select(-rleid) %>% data.frame()
```

Comment: If you repost the photo, one of us can edit it in for future users

Comment: I think the issue is that your `artprice` is a character. It should work if you do: `newdf$artprice <- as.numeric(gsub("\\$","", newdf$artprice))` and rerun.

Comment: Ok as I like to learn... why do we include \\$","" ? Is this to null out any of those missing lines, values etc?

Comment: I have a variable called artprice..... and inside the dataframe I have the column artprice. When I do the ggplot code, its making the Y axis the variable which I dont want it to do. I wish to plot the column 'artprice' not the before mentioned variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use nested if statements. For each case that would normally be labeled 1 in the output, we can check to see if the x value in the row immediately before it is < -0.1. If it is, then we label the output as 0 for that case, not 1.

The lag function that finds row-prior values can be found in the **dplyr** package in R:

```
require(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(output=ifelse(z==1 & x > -0.1,ifelse(lag(x) < -0.1,0,1),0))
```

Output:

```
          x y z output
1   0.00000 0 0      0
2   0.00000 1 0      0
3  -0.07347 1 1      1
4  -0.08351 1 1      1
5  -0.09091 1 1      1
6  -0.10624 1 1      0
7  -0.08087 1 1      0
8  -0.10677 1 1      0
9  -0.14588 1 1      0
10 -0.13901 1 1      0
11 -0.13689 1 1      0
12  0.00000 0 0      0
13  0.00000 0 0      0
14  0.00000 1 0      0
15 -0.09091 1 1      1
16  0.10624 1 1      1
17  0.08087 1 1      1
18  0.10677 1 1      1
19  0.00000 0 0      0
20  0.00000 0 0      0
```

**Edit:**

For handling multiple cases, you can use this:

```
df %>%
  group_by(rleid=rleid(z)) %>%
  mutate(outcome=as.numeric(!row_number() > row_number(z==1 & x < -0.1))) %>%
  mutate(outcome=replace(outcome,z == 1 & x < -0.1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(outcome=replace(outcome,z == 0, 0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% select(-rleid) %>% data.frame()
```

Output:

```
          x y z outcome
1   0.00000 0 0       0
2   0.00000 1 0       0
3  -0.07347 1 1       1
4  -0.08351 1 1       1
5  -0.09091 1 1       1
6  -0.10624 1 1       0
7  -0.08087 1 1       0
8  -0.05677 1 1       0
9  -0.03588 1 1       0
10 -0.02901 1 1       0
11 -0.01689 1 1       0
12  0.00000 0 0       0
13  0.00000 0 0       0
14  0.00000 1 0       0
15 -0.09091 1 1       1
16  0.10624 1 1       1
17  0.08087 1 1       1
18  0.10677 1 1       1
19  0.00000 0 0       0
20  0.00000 0 0       0
```

Comment: wow! genius - very good idea, I didn't even know about nested if statements, that is very useful!! Thanks for showing me this :)

Comment: Oh yes I just realized, what about situations where we have multiple consecutive values > -.010? Let me edit another scenario

Comment: @AndrewBannerman - Thanks, and you're welcome. I just updated the code to handle your extra conditions.

Comment: Is there a way to make z==0 as 0's? Its pretty close now! Right now when z==0 we have 1's, i'm playing with your code to see if can make it work! thanks! adding this looks like it works! another line of: mutate(outcome=replace(outcome,z == 0 & x == 0, 0)) %>%

Comment: @AndrewBannerman - There is, yes, I just made the edit to do so. The line can be even simpler than that: mutate(outcome=replace(outcome,z == 0, 0)).

Comment: Ryan - Great work! I learned something new today, I was about to go down a for loop route, with on/off features it was going to get a bit crazy, but this solution is perfect.